# Pandas Panel Merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

What is the current, best Pandas recipe for merging panel data, such as the following:

```
p = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2,5,4),
    items=['IBM', 'AA'],
    major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5),
    minor_axis=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
dp = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2,1,1),
    items=['IBM', 'Z'],
    major_axis=pd.date_range('1/8/2000', periods=1),
    minor_axis=['Close'])
```

The intended merge is like this:

```
p[:,:,'Close'].merge(dp[:,:,'Close'],
    how='outer',
    on=list(set(p.items) & set(dp.items)),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True)
```

But, I do not understand how to efficiently update the original panel p, to include this merge.

if print (p[:,:,'Close']) is this:

```
                 IBM        AA
2000-01-01  0.190049  0.200745
2000-01-02 -0.239746 -0.434157
2000-01-03 -0.112571 -0.302251
2000-01-04 -1.764957 -0.810951
2000-01-05 -0.961327  1.436247
```

Then the above table merge will look something like this:

```
                 IBM        AA         Z
2000-01-01  0.190049  0.200745       NaN
2000-01-02 -0.239746 -0.434157       NaN
2000-01-03 -0.112571 -0.302251       NaN
2000-01-04 -1.764957 -0.810951       NaN
2000-01-05 -0.961327  1.436247       NaN
2000-01-08  0.006128       NaN  0.383452
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd convert to dataframe, `combine_first`, and back again

```
new = p.to_frame().combine_first(dp.to_frame()).to_panel()

print new[:,:,'Close']

                  AA       IBM        Z
major                                  
2000-01-01  1.348884  0.472272      NaN
2000-01-02  1.599357 -0.228739      NaN
2000-01-03  2.041504 -0.325773      NaN
2000-01-04  0.348960 -0.451274      NaN
2000-01-05 -1.902347  0.146647      NaN
2000-01-08       NaN -0.240884  0.39855
```